# I'm confused about handle re-render with React JS and Virtual DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, virtual-dom

I'm using React JS but I need to learn more about Virtual DOM and benefits of it.

Apparently in Real DOM for each changes of UL the parent and children's should re-render ...

For example consider this code:

```
<ul>
   <li>List item</li>
   <li>List item</li>
   <li>List item</li>
</ul>
```

For adding an item to this UL list, after using `ul.appendChild(li)` all UL re-rendered into Browser to add a new Li item into this list. it takes time and has performance issue. because in web we have not just a single UL and maybe have a lot of elements and can be very complex that UL list.

But for virtual DOM, React takes a screenshot of our DOM and for each changes into JSX has a compare and find the best method to add new Li into UL list.

for example for above UL list, to add new item after latest can use this:

```
latestLi.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, element);
```

The above code means, React wants to add new item after or before latest element and all of UL and child's never re-render into browser...

Instead this:

```
ul.appendChild(li);
```

So after this explain, Did I get right about Virtual DOM or I need to research and this concept is not true and I've misunderstanding and mistake ?!

Thanks

Comment: read difference between virtual dom and browser dom or html dom

Comment: I've read a lot of articles, but those articles only pointed to store screenshot into an object and didn't explain how is the appending childs in this mode.

Comment: Edit your title to mention what your actual confusion is, and it might help to get better answer.

Answer (score 0):

"React takes a screenshot of our DOM" - not a screenshot, a snapshot. That is to say, it takes a copy of the DOM. When you make a change to the virtual DOM by rendering a component, React does a diff operation and only re-renders the parts of the DOM that changed. This is highly optimised and efficient.

Note that in reality, you don't need to understand much about how the Virtual DOM works in order to write React code. Just understand that it has its own DOM and that's why you need to do some things slightly differently than you would in pure JavaScript, for example using 'refs' for some types of updates that the React DOM can't handle.

Comment: Thanks, I see ... but I really like to have deep knowledge and I don't want to write code with close eyes and as a React developer I must learn concepts and write optimized codes :-)

Comment: OK, but a "deep" understanding of the React DOM is beyond the scope of a SO question. And the fact is that optimising React rarely involves any deep understanding of the virtual DOM. Understanding the component lifecycle is far more important.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping track of changes over time can be complicated and you can get into some wird edge-cases depending on the order of operations you do. It's way simpler to basically throw everything away and re-build the entire page as it should be after each change.

But this is extremely expensive with the real DOM.

That's where the Virtual DOM comes into play. It's way cheaper to build a representation of what the Page should look like after a change from scratch, without the entire overhead of the real DOM. Now React compares this representation to the internal state and takes care of the mutations to the real DOM that are necessary to get there.